# Git: How to Separate the Versioning of a Backend Rest Api and the Frontend Application in regards to Directory Structure?

Tags: javascript, git, rest, laravel, restful-architecture

I need some architectional advice on versioning on how to structure a backend that serves a REST api to a frontend application. My question is in regard on how I would build my directory structure and then initiate a git repo in them.

In my understanding I should keep the frontend and backend in **two** git repositories. One for the frontend code and one for the rest api.

Please help me understand how I do this practically. In my understanding I have the following options:

1. I put my frontend application in the `public` directory of my backend. I use a git repository for the backend but include the `public` directory in the `.gitignore` file. Then I use a `git init` in the `public` directory and version control the frontend. This approach allows me to specifiy a `csrf token` directly via php in my initial html as a sole connector.
2. I put my laravel application in the directory `my-project/backend` and my frontend in `my-project/frontend` and version control them like that. Then I just connect them through the Rest API. Just have to figure out how to solve the csrf problem.

Which of the two ways is recommended? Are there other options I haven't considered? This question is about versioning and directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic Laravel directory structure might look like follows:

```
.
├── app
├── artisan
├── bootstrap
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
├── database
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
├── phpspec.yml
├── phpunit.xml
├── public
├── readme.md
├── resources
├── server.php
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor
```

I took a quick glance over [the link](https://quickleft.com/blog/six-reasons-we-split-front-end-and-back-end-code-into-two-git-repositories-working-with-github-repositories/) you commented, and I think the big question is how large your application will be. For most web applications out there, the project structure defined above with one git repository will be sufficient. If you have a really large scale project, then it may be worth keeping everything under `public/` as a  [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: So you are saying, that separating the frontend from the backend only makes sense if the project is a really large scale project. For small projects you are saying that it just doesn't make sense. Did I understood you correctly?

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question, but it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put them in a single git repository. In general it's better to keep it simple.

Comment: I was reading this: https://quickleft.com/blog/six-reasons-we-split-front-end-and-back-end-code-into-two-git-repositories-working-with-github-repositories/